# How can I identify what ALPHA/BETA features are being used in my GCP organisation?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'd like to be able to regularly audit my gcp estate by verifying that no unapproved ALPHA/BETA features are enabled.

I can't seem to find a gcloud command that could identify this.

I recognise that this command;

```
gcloud services list
```

would list the enabled APIs of a project however is there any way of filtering on the stage of the API i.e. alpha,beta,GA?

I would then run a script to scan all my projects but of course i first need to identify the right command!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this bash script in order to check all your services within your projects and know  the activated APIs on BETA or ALPHA stage.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(gcloud projects list --format="get(projectId)"); do
    echo "Project ID: $i"
    gcloud config set project $i > /dev/null 2>&1
    SERVICES="$(gcloud services list | grep -E 'beta-*|alpha-*')"
    if test -z "$SERVICES" 
     then
      echo "No BETA/APLHA services"
     else
      echo "$SERVICES"
    fi
    echo ""
done
```